# How to test external POST call that receives query parameters as arrays instead of single values?

Tags: django, rest, webhooks, paddle-paddle

Has anybody successfully managed to write tests for a Paddle webhook in a Django application?

Paddle sends messages as POST requests to a webhook. According to [Paddle's webhook testing](https://vendors.paddle.com/webhook-alert-test) an exemplary request looks like this:

```json
[alert_id] => 1865992389
[alert_name] => payment_succeeded
[...] => ...
```

The webhook at my Django application receives this as the `request.POST=<QueryDict>` parameter:

```json
{'alert_id': ['1865992389'], 'alert_name': ['payment_succeeded'], '...': ['...']}
```

That is, all values are received as arrays, not values.

Contrary, my webhook test looks like the message format I would expect, i.e. uses values instead of arrays:

```py
    response = client.post('/pricing/paddlewebhook/',
                           {'alert_name': 'payment_succeeded',
                            'alert_id': '1865992389',
                            '...': '...',
                            },
                           content_type='application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
    assert response.status_code == 200  # Match paddle's expectation
```

This is received by the webhook as `request.POST=<QueryDict>` parameter:

```json
{'alert_name': 'payment_succeeded', 'alert_id': '1865992389', '...': '...'}
```

The webhook itself is a simple POST method of a class-based view:

```py
# Django wants us to apply the csrf_exempt decorator all methods via dispatch() instead of just to post().
@method_decorator(csrf_exempt, name='dispatch')
class PaddleWebhook(View):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        logger.info("request.POST=%s", request.POST)
        # ...
```

Is it really suitable testing behaviour to change the test (and the view's `post()`) to include array values or am I missing something obvious about external calls to POST webhooks?

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution ("working for me") is to define and use an intermediate method to "adjust" the incoming parameter dict:

```py
    def _extractArrayParameters(self, params_dict: dict) -> dict:
        """Returns a parameter dict that contains values directly instead of single element arrays.
        Needed as messages from paddle are received as single element arrays.
        """
        ret = dict()
        for k, v in params_dict.items():
            # Convert all single element arrays directly to values.
            if isinstance(v, list) and len(v) == 1:
                ret[k] = v[0]
            else:
                ret[k] = v
        return ret
```

However, this feels dirty, even though it makes all tests pass.